# JSInterop seems to stop working on Blazor server when Environment is changed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

when I change from "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" to "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging" some scripts stop working, like it is unable to find them, for instance:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.ErrorBoundary: Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44303/_content/BlazorPro.BlazorSize/blazorSizeMediaModule.js
> TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44303/_content/BlazorPro.BlazorSize/blazorSizeMediaModule.js

> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44303/_content/BlazorPro.BlazorSize/blazorSizeMediaModule.js
> TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44303/_content/BlazorPro.BlazorSize/blazorSizeMediaModule.js
> at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
> at BlazorPro.BlazorSize.MediaQueryService.CreateMediaQueryList(DotNetObjectReference`1 dotNetObjectReference)
> at BlazorPro.BlazorSize.MediaQueryList.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Any ideas why this behavior might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize/issues/71

basically I had to enable static web assets in the webhost:

```js
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets(); // <----
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```